# How to call function from button located in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a GridView on my page and single column of this view consists of buttons. On clicking these buttons, I want a method to be called which is located at code behind page. I have tried, OnClick of button and OnRowCommand of GridView. However, I still cannot call the function from code behind page.

This is my GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    CssClass="formx2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="companyName"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Düzenle" SortExpression="companyName" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="colDept">      
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="IncreaseButton" Text="Düzenle" 
                    CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="something" 
                    CssClass="accordionHeader" BorderColor ="White" 
                    Onclick="redirect"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my code behind method,

```
protected void redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "test";
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, I really stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i believe it is onRowCommand not just RowCommand, unless you just made a typo in your question

Comment: i tried OnRowCommand. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: If you would add OnClick-handler in the codebehind(at least protected) with the name `redirect` and with a signature `(Object sender, EventArgs e)`, it would work for sure. Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: No error at all. I have redirect method just as you described but it is not working. It just refreshes the page.

Comment: I agree with Tim Schmelter. add `protected void redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)` to handle the onclick event...

Comment: I have updated my question and added the function you described. Unfortunately it is not working. I do not get any error messages. It just does nothing. By the way I use debugger to detect whether function is called or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Düzenle" SortExpression="companyName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="colDept">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Button ID="IncreaseButton" runat="server" 
    CommandName="Select" 
    CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
     />
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and then code behind

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
  If (e.CommandName = "Select") Then
    // Retrieve the row index stored in the CommandArgument property.
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

    // Retrieve the row that contains the button 

    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)

    // Add code here 
  End If
 End Sub
```